# How to retrieve the save checkbox value in the editable form in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

Data is save to DB, Retrieve the data in enabled checkbox. How can I write code for edit the form in `views.py file`

In models username field is the foreign key of Emp_Profile model and Process is the foreign key of Client_Process table

**Models.py**

```
class Emp_Process(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(Emp_Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    process = models.ForeignKey(Client_Process, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class Meta:
        db_table : 'emp_process'
```

**html file**

```
{% extends 'client_pannel.html'  %}
{% block content %}
<br><br>
<br><br>
<div class="data-table-area mg-b-15">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="sparkline13-list">
                    <div class="sparkline13-hd">
                        <div class="main-sparkline13-hd">
                                <label>{{ emp.first_name }} {{ emp.last_name }} - {{ emp.designation }}</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sparkline13-graph">
                        <div class="datatable-dashv1-list custom-datatable-overright">
                            <table id="table" data-toggle="table" data-pagination="true" data-search="true" data-show-columns="true" data-show-pagination-switch="true" data-show-refresh="true" data-key-events="true" data-show-toggle="true" data-resizable="true" data-cookie="true"
                                data-cookie-id-table="saveId" data-show-export="true" data-click-to-select="true" data-toolbar="#toolbar">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th >Client</th>
                                        <th>Process</th>

                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                        {% for client in form %}
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="cname[]" value="{{ client.id }}">
                                                {{ client.Name }}
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                {% for process in client.clients %}
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="process[]" value="{{ process.id }}">
                                                {{ process.process }}<br />
                                                {% endfor %}
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**Views.py**
In views file I get the employee details via the ID

```
def Edit_Assigning(request, id):
form = Client.objects.all()
emp = Emp_Profile.objects.get(pk=id)
for i in range(len(form)):
    clients = Client.objects.filter(Name=form[i])
    object = Client.objects.filter(Name=form[i]).values('id')
    clients = Client_Process.objects.filter(client_id__in=object)
    form[i].clients = clients
return render(request, 'edit_assigning.html',{'emp': emp,'form':form})
```

Comment: where's your view?

Comment: I added the views file in my Question, Please refer

Comment: so what does `{% for client in form %}` do if `form` isn't defined in your context?

Comment: sorry wrongly edited question now added the correct views file, please refer

Comment: you should use a `ModelForm` for editing `Emp_Process`, this will automatically create a dropdown for the `process` field that the user can choose from. If you want checkbox instead of <select>, just change the widget of the form field. Read the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/)

Comment: No, I can't use ModelForm, Because the data came from another one model(table)

Comment: your view code is totally obscure and unreadable. `form` is a list of `Client` objects, then for each `client` in the list you assign `clients` to be the related `Client_Process` objects (you don't even need to do that because `client.client_process_set` is already that, refer to [one-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#one-to-many-relationships)). But basically `Emp_Profile` has a many-to-many relationship to `Client_Process` (you should do that instead of defining `Emp_Process` yourself), and you should use a ModelForm for `Emp_Profile`.

Comment: Anyway, what does `request.POST.getlist('process[]')` give you when you submit your html form?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197786/discussion-between-dhinakaran-and-dirkgroten).

Comment: request.POST.getlist('process[]') I list the table data

Comment: can anyone here explain why `:` instead of `=` in `db_table : 'emp_process'` ????

Comment: That is just a table name 'emp_process'